# Get integer list from a webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

How can I get an List from a WebApi?

So far I have the Api method:

```
    public IList<int> GetKeywordIdsById([FromBody]string id)
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                return _categoryService.GetKeywordIdsById(Convert.ToInt32(id));
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

How can I invoke it and extract the List ?

So far I call it like this but Result is from type String, so how can I convert it to List?:

```
public List<int> GetKeywordIdsById(int id)
{
    try
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(API_BASE_URL);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            return client.GetAsync("api/category/getkeywordidsbyid/" + id).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        logger.Log(LogLevel.Info, e);

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this :

```
client.GetAsync("api/category/getkeywordidsbyid/" + id).Result.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<int>>().Result;
```

Please refer to this article on asp.net :

> [Calling a Web API From a .NET Client (C#)](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)

Comment: Great! Thanks! The famous red line under the code is gone! :)

Answer (score 0):

[JavaScriptSeralizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
var sr = new JavaScriptSerializer();
int[] arr = sr.Deserialize<int[]>(arrJSON);
```

`arrJSON` is a string response you received from your http GetAsync call.